# Open Suse only root can use service

Tags: opensuse, services, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Noob Question
I am using OpenSuse Tumbleweed in WSL Windows 11. I am unable to use service to start or check the status of applications as a regular user. Only Root.

I get the following error:

`service: only root can use service`

Edit: Also Noticed i am not allowed to ping as a normal user as i get the following error:

```
user@device: ping -v 1.1.1.1
ping: socket: operation not permitted
ping: socket: operation not permitted
```

There was no wheel group when i installed this if that helps. I had to make a wheel group and add my user to it to allow sudo permissions

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: work as design.

In UNIX/Linux service management is (mostly) for `root` user. If you want to exec a operation as ordinary user you can try command:

```
sudo service httpd status
```

(for example)
Or become root user and then manage services. Or if you know the root password:

```
su - -c service httpd status
```

(the first dash is not a mistake, it tell `su` to get the environment of target user (in this case `root`)

Comment: Is there a way to allow activities like this for regular users.

I have shifted from Ubuntu and Manjaro where in I could use service and systemctl as regular issues to check service status

Comment: @NehalGowrish, the best and safe way is to use `sudo`

Comment: I am not able to ping either, is that normal?

Comment: @NehalGowrish, do not know, have no experience with SuSE